Install Ubuntu 24.04. problems with two disks
I want to use ubuntu on my laptop, which was working with windows before. Therefore I made a bootable USB stick. With it I want to destroy the windows software and install the ubuntu version 24.04.
The laptop is created with two disks (256GB per disk). Windows made them working together with Raid0. I would also like them to work together the same way on Ubuntu.
Is there anyone, who has an idea or a solution, what I should do?
My laptop model is Acer Aspire R7-371T

RAID 0 is not recommended. Don't bother with RAID 0 unless you have a specific need for speed without data redundancy, since if one drive goes out, you lose the whole array. Many with RAID 0 break RAID and just use the two disks. And you can then use second drive as part of backup. Those who want speed now convert to SSD or if hardware supports it NVMe SSD.
